# How to set focus to the last row in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

How to set focus to the absolute last row?
I tried all the solutions I found in StackOverflow, but it always goes to the Row before the last, not the last one.

when I edit a value in the `Quantity` Column and press enter, I add two rows: the colored one which is read-only and also another row where I can add the next item.

Now, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the quantity, the focus goes to second row quantity: I need it to go to the first Column (`Barcode`) of the last row.

```
private void onCellEditEnd(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if(header == barcode)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value = item.Qty;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value = item.Item;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value = item.Mrp;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[4].Value = item.Discount;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[5].Value = item.Cgst;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[6].Value = item.Sgst;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[7].Value = item.Amount;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index+1].Cells[1].Value = item.Details;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index+1].Cells[4].Value = item.Discount;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index+1].Cells[5].Value = item.Cgst;
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index+1].Cells[6].Value = item.Sgst;
            
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2];
    }
    else if(header == quantity)
    {
        dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows[2].Cell[0]; //tried this
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Selected = true; //tried this
    }
}
```

The second row is part of the first row, so on the CellEndEdit of `Quantity` I want the focus to go to the 3rd Row, in the `Barcode` Column, which I have added in the last line of code, using `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code of what you have tried? That will make it easier for people to help identify the problem :-)

Comment: I am not following exactly what you are asking. If you want to “change” the behavior of the “where” the next cell is selected when the user presses the “enter” key while editing a cell… then I suggest looking at the grid’s `KeyDown` event. There you can check if the user pressed the “enter” key, then set the grids current cell to the cell of your choice.

Comment: i tried dataGrid.Rows[dataGrid.RowCount - 1].Selected = true; 
and dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows[2].Cell[0]; in which index 2 is out of range .
tried various other solution but it never seem to focus on last row...its like it doesnt identify there is a 3rd row..

Comment: Where is the code executing… `dataGrid.Rows[dataGrid.RowCount - 1].Selected = true;` ? You show no code so it is a guess. Also, setting a cell as “selected” may work, however the grids `CurrentCell` and a “Selected” cell may not necessarily be the same cells. I suggest setting the grids `CurrentCell` to the cell you want.

Comment: ok sorry .. i'll add the code ..its my first question

Comment: @johnG please can you check the code ... this is what im trying to do

Comment: @johnG the second row is part of the first row..so on cell edit end of quantity i want the focus to goto 3rd row which i have added at the last line using dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); ...

Comment: There are many questions. Why is the code specific to the rows 2 and 3? What if there are more or less than 3 or 4 or 5 or more rows? If the user edits ANY Quantity value… do you want the current cell to drop down to the Barcode cell in the “last” row in the grid? Why is the code managing the grid’s “new” rows? The grid has a “new” row feature that works and manually adding the rows is just extra work for you.

Comment: Why is the code manually managing the grids rows? A data source to the grid would make things much easier. Why is the new row made read-only? What do you mean by… _”The second row is part of the first row”_ …? Can you provide better details as to how you want the grid to behave when the user does such and such and please be specific.

Comment: Currently, it appears you are making this far more complicated than it has to be… whatever you are trying to accomplish. And without question, you should use a `DataSource` for the grid. Manually managing the rows in the grid only “creates” more work for you. I suggest a `BindingSource/BindingList`.

Comment: im a beginner , so my code may be bad .. 
 Why is the code specific to the rows 2 and 3? - the code is not specific to rows 2 and 3 ..im just doing it for testing ..it should always go to last row ..
If the user edits ANY Quantity value… do you want the current cell to drop down to the Barcode cell in the “last” row in the grid? - yes
Why is the code manually managing the grids rows? A data source to the grid would make things much easier - i tried using datasource , but could not make it to work ..so i did it manually.

Comment: Can you provide better details as to how you want the grid to behave when the user does such and such and please be specific. - first there is an empty row , user types barcode then press enter ... required details like mrp discount sgst cgst amount are fetched from an array and is populated in the row .... also the second row is added which is the details row of this item that i fetched from the barcode .... the focus goes to quantity field .. user types quantity and press enter ..  a third empty row is added , and the focus should goto barcode cell of that row ..inorder to add the next item

Answer (score 0):

To select a specific row you must use

`dataGrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;`

Wherever you make a change and you want the **last row** to be selected, you must use the following code :

```
dataGrid.Rows[dataGrid.RowCount - 1].Selected = true;
```

Comment: i tried this .. but it still goes to second row

Comment: You are wrong somewhere. When do you want the last row to be selected?

Comment: i hace updated the question .. can you check if you understand ...

Comment: This line dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows [2] .Cell [0]; Gives an error because it is in use. But the last row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you a couple weeks ago this is what I did.

```
    private void gridControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                int indexOfRecent = gridView1.DataRowCount - 1;
                gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = indexOfRecent; 
            }
        }
```