# How to move to last empty row in DataGridView in C# programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am removing a row from DataGridView in WinForms. I want to move to the last empty row using code. For removing I am using this line

```
  OrderItemsGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
```

I tried to use this line

```
  OrderItemsGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = OrderItemsGridView.RowCount;
```

but it is out of range because I think it does not count the empty one. If I change it to (RowCount -1) then it will take the last row (not the empty one)

Any suggestion?

This is similar to this question, but it has not been answered.
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68572059/how-to-set-focus-to-the-last-row-in-a-datagridview)
I hope if someone has any suggestion

[image]

Comment: I need the empty row at the end to add new value. I can do that and add a new empty row from the code. But the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the first cell of the last row and begin editing like this:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.NewRowIndex].Cells[0];
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

Using [NewRowIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.newrowindex?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property you know what's the index of the last row. Then using [CurrentCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property you can set the current cell, and finally using [BeginEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method you can start editing.

Comment: This is very nice. It does solve the issue. Thank you